# MacOS editing xml files with sed

Tags: xml, macos, unix, sed

Background: I am trying to edit a couple hundred of xml files- I need to parse the title of the file and then place elements of that title in the file itself.
an example of a title is

```
File=object.34.xml
```

The parsing is done, so that

```
echo $num1 
34
```

I then try sed to replace a certain object in the xml file with OBJECT34

```
sed -i "" "/s/object/OBJECT$num1/" >$File
```

which gives me a invalid command code O error...
Suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The input file is missing. And you must remove the first  `/`. Try:

```
sed -i "" "s/object/OBJECT$num1/" $File
```